# Is there a better way to add items to dict with a list as value better?

Tags: python

I usually do this if check:

```
new_value = 'xxx'
if key in my_dict:
    values = my_dict[key]
    values.append(new_value)
    my_dict[key] = values
else:
    my_dict[key] = [new_value]
```

I feel there may be a more concise way to do this, but I always do this.

Comment: well for starters, your `if` block could simply be `my_dict[key].append(new_value)`, there's no point to `my_dict[key] = values`... but for this sort of thing you can either use the `.setdefault` method or a `collections.defaultdict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict`s are what you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict['key'].append('value')
my_dict
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'key': ['value']})
```

Comment: What about if I need a SortedDict, not a general dict? Does the defaultdict still work?

Comment: No, it is not sorted. There are, in general, very few reasons to have a sorted dictionary. What is yours?

Comment: I wanted to keep the insertion order of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use [setdefault](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm)

```
mydict.setdefault('xxx', []).append(new_value)
```

Syntax

```
dict.setdefault(key, default=None)
```

- key: This is the key to be searched.
- default: This is the Value to be returned in case key is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You could cut out a couple of lines by skipping straight to the append:

```
new_value = 'xxx'
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key].append(new_value)
    else:
        my_dict[key] = [new_value]
```

Comment: Please indent your code.